# VueJS 2/Bootstrap 4 - Prevent a focus on element from bootstrap 4's data-toggle event

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4

Using VueJS2 and Bootstrap 4, I created a custom directive to interact with the changes that occurs with Bootstrap 4 radio button group. The problem occurs that when you update the data for bootstrap 4, the element component gets focused, which is fine if the page is small. But if the page is long and scrollable, this becomes a burden.

The below code is copied and modified based from the following example:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" data-toggle="buttons" v-radio="oType">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-dark active">
        <input type="radio" name="oType" value="0" /> Pressure
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-dark">
        <input type="radio" name="oType" value="1" /> Vacuum
    </label>
</div>
```

I created the following vue custom directive (radio.js): 
**Note**: the problem is not on bind, the problem is only with the inserted/updated hooks, which are exactly the same code copied.

```
export default {
    inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        var btns = $(el).find('.btn');
        var radioGrpName = $(btns[0]).find('input')[0].name;
        $("input[name='" + radioGrpName + "'][value='" + binding.value + "']").closest('.btn').button('toggle');
    },
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        var btns = $(el).find('.btn');
        btns.each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                var v = $(this).find('input').get(0).value;
                (function set(obj, str, val) {
                    str = str.split('.');
                    while (str.length > 1) {
                        obj = obj[str.shift()];
                    }
                    return obj[str.shift()] = val;
                })(vnode.context, binding.expression, v);
            })
        })
    },
    update: function (el, binding, vnode, oldnode) {
        var btns = $(el).find('.btn');
        var radioGrpName = $(btns[0]).find('input')[0].name;
        $("input[name='" + radioGrpName + "'][value='" + binding.value + "']").closest('.btn').button('toggle');
    }
}
```

The problem is, if I have the bootstrap 4 radio button group somewhere down the page, and I have a user set some kind of input data that automatically changes the data for the radio button, this triggers the buttons('toggle') from the directive (using either the insert or update hooks), focusing on the element, making a big jump in the html page. Users would have to scroll back up to continue where they left off.

The way the radio button above interacts with data changed is by a computed property:

```
computedProperty: {
    oType: {
        get: function () {
            return this.oType;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this.oType = value
        }
    }
}
```

So how do you prevent a focus from happening on the element?

Comment: it would be a lot easier to help you if you are able to put a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on codesandbox/jsfiddel

Comment: You're right, but it's very difficult for me as well to set up. I spent an hour trying to get the resources all set up, but it wasn't working exactly on jsfiddle. I traced the bug all the way to bootstrap.js.. so I had to replace that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I traced the problem to bootstrap.js, and during the trigger of data-toggle, it caused the problem to occur. So in radio.js, I switched this line:

```
$("input[name='" + radioGrpName + "'][value='" + binding.value + "']").closest('.btn').button('toggle');
```

and mimicked the look & feel:

```
$(el).children('.btn').removeClass('active');
$("input[name='" + radioGrpName + "'][value='" + binding.value + "']").closest('.btn').addClass('active');
$("input[name='" + radioGrpName + "'][value='" + binding.value + "']").prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Boostrap v4.3 calls focus() and even fires a change event when we call .button('toggle'); Bootstrap v5 seems to be [removing](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/30650) these side-effects.